# Facing error on login authentication laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```php
if ($validator->passes()) {
  if (Auth::guard('admin')
    ->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
      ],
      $request->get('remember')
    )
  ) {
    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
  }
}
```

> Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct(): **Argument #2 ($provider) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given**, called in D:\path\vendor\laravel\framework\src\**Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php** on line 127

Login with matching credentials in Laravel, but it's showing an error on the `authenticate` line. There is an error on this line.